# Type error from setting defaultValues of react-hook-form's useForm to a generic value

Tags: typescript, react-hook-form

Here's backbone example (You can also find this on this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/useform-defaultvalues-9mqcsk?file=/src/useFooForm.ts:0-444))

```
import { FieldValues, useForm } from "react-hook-form";

type FooForm<T> = {
  name: string;
  height: number;
} & T;

type UseFooFormOptions<T> = {
  initialFooForm: FooForm<T>;
};

export const useFooForm = <T extends FieldValues>({
  initialFooForm
}: UseFooFormOptions<T>) => {
  const form = useForm<FooForm<T>>({
    // Type 'FooForm<T>' is not assignable to type 'DefaultValues<FooForm<T>>'.ts(2322)
    defaultValues: initialFooForm
  });

  const someOtherReturns = 5;

  return {
    ...form,
    someOtherReturns
  };
};
```

Why type `FooForm<T>` is not assignable to type `DefaultValues<FooForm<T>>`? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
type UseFooFormOptions<T> = {
  initialFooForm: FooForm<T>;
};
```

To

```
import { FieldValues, DefaultValues, useForm } from "react-hook-form";

//...

type UseFooFormOptions<T> = {
  initialFooForm: DefaultValues<FooForm<T>>;
};
```

`useForm` expects that the base values type has a `DefaultValues` type applied to it for the `defaultValues` property. That's because `defaultValues` can specify a *subset* of values as opposed to providing all of them.

However, it is curious that `FooForm<T>` is not, therefore, a compatible value for `DefaultValues<FooForm<T>>`. Sadly, it looks like this is because `DeepPartial` is implemented in the library in such a way as to break TS's inference between these types, which it uses under the hood.

If you wanted to force all the values to be provided to `initialFooForm` you'd have to instead leave `UseFooFormOptions` as it was and, unfortunately, do a cast:

```
  const form = useForm<FooForm<T>>({
    defaultValues: initialFooForm as DefaultValues<FooForm<T>>
  });
```